# Как обновлять координаты эллипса на QGraphicsScene?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene

Сделал форму, добавил на неё сцену и хочу, чтобы по нажатию на клавишу, объект, созданный на сцене, начал передвигаться.

broun_dvig.h

```
#ifndef BROUN_DVIG_H
#define BROUN_DVIG_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QPen>
#include <QTimer>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class Broun_dvig; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class Broun_dvig : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Broun_dvig(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Broun_dvig();

private slots:
    void on_btn_start_clicked();
    void On_Timer();

private:
    Ui::Broun_dvig *ui;
    QGraphicsScene * scena;
    QGraphicsEllipseItem* ellipse;
    QTimer timer;
    double fi = rand()*2*3.14;
    double t = 0;
    double dt = 0.1;
    double x,
           y,
          x0,
          y0;

};
#endif // BROUN_DVIG_H
```

broun_dvig.cpp

```
#include "broun_dvig.h"
#include "ui_broun_dvig.h"

#include <QPen>
#include <cmath>

Broun_dvig::Broun_dvig(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Broun_dvig)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    scena = new QGraphicsScene;


    ui->graphicsView->resize(600,600);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scena);
}

Broun_dvig::~Broun_dvig()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Broun_dvig::on_btn_start_clicked()
{


    QPen pen(Qt::green, 3, Qt::DashDotLine, Qt::RoundCap, Qt::RoundJoin);
    QBrush br;

    ellipse=scena->addEllipse(x, y, 20, 20, pen, br);

    updateGeometry();
    timer.start();
}

void Broun_dvig :: On_Timer()
{
    x += x * pow(fi,2) * t;
    y += y * pow(fi,2) * t;
    t+=dt;
  this->repaint();
}
```

Comment: просто используйте setPos или moveBy методы итема

Comment: setPos:ellipse
A вот дальше как? Если не сложно можете сказать, правильный ли код?

Comment: что дальше? какой код правильный?

Comment: код, который указан выше. Не понимаю, как и где использовать setPos().

Comment: а что по вашему означает правильный код? Есть ведь лексика, синтаксис, семантика, логика... Код может быть верным синтаксически, но неверным логически. Полагаю вас интересует именно логическая корректность, но, увы, это может определять только тот, кто определяет требования к программе (грубо говоря: что и как программа должна делать). Я не знаю что вы хотите сделать, так что не могу судить.

Comment: Что же касается setPos - ну так используйте его когда хотите установить объект в определенную позицию. Название говорит само за себя.